# Why created dynamically drop down box not looks good?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I use jQuery mobile 1.4.5 and jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery-ui- 1.9.2

I create dropbox dynamically here the JavaScript code:

```
function setLayerPropertyControls() {

    var content = '<fieldset style="border: solid 1px #6b6b6b;">';

    content += '<label for="select-native-1">Basic:</label>' +
              '<select name="select-native-1" id="select-native-1">' +
                   '<option value="1">The 1st Option</option>' +
                   '<option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>' +
                   '<option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>' +
                   '<option value="4">The 4th Option</option>' +
               '</select>';

    content += '</fieldset>';
    layerProp.append(content);
}
```

Here is html markup:

```
<div data-role="page" id="layerProperty">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1 id="layers property"></h1>
        <a href="#mapPage" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-l">חזור</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="vectorLayerProperties">
        </div>
        <div id="vectorLayerslist"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the result in the view:

[image]

While if I take this code:

```
 <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="select-native-1">Basic:</label>
        <select name="select-native-1" id="select-native-1">
            <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
            <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
            <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
            <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

And paste it in HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="layerProperty">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1 id="layers property"></h1>
        <a href="#mapPage" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-l">חזור</a>
    </div>


    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="vectorLayerProperties">

            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="select-native-1">Basic:</label>
                <select name="select-native-1" id="select-native-1">
                    <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
                    <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
                    <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
                    <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
                </select>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="vectorLayerslist"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

It looks looks like that:

[image]

Any idea why do I get poor style of the drop down-box when I try to create it dynamically in the code?

Comment: How do you initialize `layerProp` variable?

Comment: In your dynamically generated code you don't have the div with class `ui-field-contain`

Comment: well, please show your head, using jQuery Mobile and jQuery UI together is an "advanced" topic and can influence the solution - if you don't absolutely need both, maybe you should pick a choice.

Answer (score -2):

your dynamically code has this
`<fieldset style="border: solid 1px #6b6b6b;"> </fieldset>;`
but pure html not have.

so i think maybe is css layer problom?